# Is it legal to use third-party apps to bypass Apple's Activation Lock?

Tags: united-states, software

I have a used iPad in my possession but can't use it due to Apple's Activation Lock. To prevent theft of Apple's devices, Activation Lock requires an ID and password in order to use the device. While I didn't steal the device, I don't know the previous owner's ID and password. Would using third-party software to bypass Activation Lock be legal? Since the answer may depend on what software is used, I'll use UnlockGo as an example, which claims to be legal [here](https://itoolab.com/support/technical-faqs/unlockgo/).

Is the source accurate in claiming that UnlockGo is legal? I'm asking this on the Law StackExchange since the question isn't how to use the app but whether doing so is legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you legally obtained that device, it’s totally legal.  It’s no different than jailbreaking, and that’s been discussed a lot on stack exchange. In fact, this question is maybe a duplicate.

Comment: Obvious addition: Buying stolen goods, whether you knew or not that they are stolen, means you didn't legally obtain the device. Accessing someone else's data is also illega (for example if a bailiff took the phone legally)l. On the other hand, I know someone who's job it is among other things to collect devices from people leaving the company, and many of them come back locked.